# Making System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable as Enumerable

Tags: asp.net, controls

I want to iterate through HtmlTable (Server Side) in ASP.NET 3.5.

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow trow in someTable)
{
       var x = trow.InnerText; 
}
```

I received an error message that `"System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable"` does not contain a definition for GetEnumerator.

How to write an extension method or alternative to make HtmlTable as enumerable row collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to iterate over the table - presumably you're wanting to iterate over the *rows* in the table - check [this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.rows%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Are you going for something more like this?

```
foreach (HtmlTableRow trow in someTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in trow.Cells)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```